Importing an existing product into a new category and the URL is the default
I have 2 different stores: German and French. I have the same SKU "A" on both stores, with the German and French URLs. I created a new category on the French store, and when I import the product the URL that is generated is in German (looks like the default) instead in French. Does anybody know why it is happening?
Thank you in advance!

Please make sure the scope of url_key attribute is storeview.
